Wait until text appears in the text box
I need to wait until text appears in the text box in my application. The problem is, text usually loads from 1 to 5 seconds, sometimes more, and some text boxes don't contain text, which makes it impossible to use cypress-wait-until, because it just waits for text to appear and fails the test after 60sec when it doesn't load. Here's my current implementation:
cy.get(elementSelector)
    .if()
    .find(this.helpTextArea)
    .then(($helptextBox) => {
        let helptext = $helptextBox.text();
        helptext = helptext.trim() ? helptext : null;

        if (additionalHelptext) {
            questionModel.additionalHelptext = helptext;
        } else {
            questionModel.helptext = helptext;
        }
    });

I suppose that the most effective solution would be some soft assertion which doesn't fail the test on textboxes without text, but from what I know, Cypress doesn't support any kind of soft assertions.
Tried: cypress-wait-until (fails when text is not found), cy.wait() (increases the time of test execution and is not reliable).

Your test should be as deterministic as possible, so using flaky functions like waitUntil is not recommended.
Instead, increase the timeout of your query, since you say "something more than 5 seconds" I would guess that 10 seconds would be a suitable upper limit.
You can build your selector with string interpolation.
To get the text, invoke text() and it will return the text or empty string.
cy.get(`${elementSelector} ${this.helpTextArea}`)
  .invoke('text')
  .then(helptext => {
    if (helptext) {
      // process helptext here
    } else {
      // use additional text here
    }
  })


Doesn't seem like a solution. It'll just retrieve empty text if it's not loaded yet. What I need is to wait until it appears in the textbox or continue the test if text hasn't been found.

If you want to wait until text that is loading appears in a textbox, the usual way is to add an assertion.
"Sometimes it's more than 5 seconds" - how much more?
Say, bump the timeout to 10 seconds.
cy.get(elementSelector)                                         <-- |
  .find(helpTextArea, {timeout:10_000})                             |
  .should('not.have.text', '')           // loop back if not so --> |
  .invoke('text')                        // then proceed on down the chain
  .then(text => {
     // use the text
  })

